# Using Stage 3D inside a Direct3D or OpenGL application

Tags: flash, activex, stage3d

Before there was Stage 3D, I could simply capture the output of flash rendering engine with an in-place site and use it as a texture. But now, there is the Stage 3D which seems can't be rendered windowless...

Is there a way to capture the output of a the flash control running in direct mode? Or is there a way to let them render to a supplied surface?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture Stage3D buffer into BitmapData

Try method [Context3D.drawToBitmapData()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Context3D.html#drawToBitmapData%28%29)

```
    var renderedBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(viewWidth, viewHeight, true);
    renderContext.drawToBitmapData(renderedBitmapData);

    renderContext.present();

    //Add to stage
    bitmap = new Bitmap(renderedBitmapData);
    this.addChild(bitmap);
```

Comment: And how should I send the bitmap to the native host?

Comment: @BlueWanderer you have a native app with Flash plugin running inside rendering something and you want it displayed in the app, not in the plugin?

Comment: right. I want to use the content of flash movieclip as animated texture. And it's easy without stage3d. Actually I've already given it up. Stage3d is not that useful for me here.

Comment: @BlueWanderer that you would need to convert movie clip into spritesheet texture, upload to Context3D, render, download the BitmapData... that is not the way to render flash MovieClip into bitmap :)

Comment: @BlueWanderer maybe you should ask what you need to do, why exactly you wanted Stage3D inside you app

Comment: My application can use movieclips as textures, but if a movieclip uses stage3d, it won't work. And I end up told the users never use stage3d with my application. lol